# How to only remove "default" from url on magento 2?

Tags: url, magento2

I want to remove "default" from url but don't affect other languages Store Code
for example:
from "http://www.example.com/default" to "http://www.example.com"
keep "http://www.example.com/fr" or other url with store code like this

Answer (score -1):

Go to Admin->Stores->All Store and click on store in which you want to change and remove.
"http://www.example.com/default" to "http://www.example.com"
keep "http://www.example.com/fr" or other url with store code like this